# How to ignore a column of a TableModel in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I have a `TableModel` to a `JTable` and I must put it on another table, and I've done it just seting the model of the second table with `setModel(firstTableModel)`.

The problem is that I don't want that one of the columns of the model shows on the second table.

Is it possible to ignore/not display a single column, or I really must create another `TableModel` with all the redundant information of the first table model to omit just a single column?

Comment: if you are using DefaultTableModel, you are in for a world of hurt. If on the other hand you have your own Model derived from AbstractTableModel, it's pretty easy to share table models, by inheriting a small class the modifies the base with in your case, what columns to show.

Comment: @Frakcool It's my own model, how can I show the columns that I want?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: JTable.removeColumn(TableColumn aColumn), this column isn only removed from JTables view, this Column is still in XxxTableModel and TableColum, this process is reversable in  JTables view, more in JTable / TableColumn APIs

Comment: @mKorbel Thank you, it works!

Comment: @halierier you are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @mKorbel I found the solution:

`secondTable.removeColumn(secondTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnIndex));`